# Unable to launch Azure Cosmos Emulator on my Windows 10 PC

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage-emulator

I am unable to get cosmos emulator started.  I keep getting a “This site can’t be reached.  Localhost refused to connect” message when it tries to navigate to https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html.  Several seconds later, I get the below error message:

[image]

I'm using the latest version (2.4.5.0).  I uninstalled Cosmos Emulator, deleted the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator` folder, and reinstalled.  Still same issue.

Then, I tried running `LODCTR /R` in the command prompt twice, but that didn’t do anything for me.  I’m out of ideas.  This was working for me several months ago, so something happened recently that caused it to stop working.  What could be causing this issue?  Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the steps mentioned **[`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#troubleshooting)** to troubleshoot your issue

If you installed a new version of the emulator and are experiencing errors, ensure you reset your data. You can reset your data by right-clicking the Azure Cosmos Emulator icon on the system tray, and then clicking Reset Data…. If that does not fix the errors, you can uninstall the emulator and any older versions of the emulator if found, remove "C:\Program files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator" directory and reinstall the emulator

Comment: I tried resetting the data, but I still get the same issue.  Also, I completely uninstalled and deleted the "C:\Program files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator" folder as well as the %LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator folder.  But, I'm still seeing the issue.  Could it be something messed up in the windows registry?